# What sort of spaces show up as intersection complexes of toric degenerations of Calabi-Yau Varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties, mirror-symmetry, calabi-yau

Roughly, a toric degeneration is a proper flat family $f:\mathcal{X}\to D$ of relative dimension $n$ with the properties that $\mathcal{X}_t$ is an irreducible normal Calabi-Yau and $\mathcal{X}_0$ is a union of toric varieties, glued along toric sub-varieties.  The intersection complex $B$ of this is a real $n$-manifold with a polyhedral decomposition given by the way the aforementioned toric varieties intersect.

I'm interested in what sort of spaces show up as intersection complexes of toric degenerations.  For $K3$ surfaces this is known: $B$ is either a point (the smooth case), a line, or $S^2$ (if I'm understanding the literature correctly). These are sometimes called Type I, II, and III degenerations.

Is there anything known or conjectured for higher dimensions? Perhaps if we put some stronger conditions on the family?

Comment: I don't think you can have a toric degeneration of K3 surfaces of type I.

Comment: As in Sasha's comment, toric degenerations are too restrictive for these questions (in type II for K3s elliptic curves appear as intersections); usually one considers snc or toroidal. In https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08320.pdf, Question 7, it is asked if the dual complex is always homeomorphic to a sphere, as soon as it has dimension n. See (34) in that paper where it's explained why it's at least homology sphere.

Comment: @EvgenyShinder You're absolutely right, I was conflating toric degenerations and the more general Kulikov degenerations.  The paper you linked discusses exactly the sort of things I was interested in, thanks!